# Finding a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f(\frac{1}{3^n})=\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}$ , for $n\in\{0,1,2,...\}=I$;  $f(1-\frac{1}{2^{m}})=1-\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}, m\in I$ and $f(x)=x$ elsewhere in $[0,1]$. Does this work?

Note:

$\frac{1}{3^n}=1-\frac{1}{2^m} \implies 2^m+3^n=2^m3^n$, an impossibility, since LHS is odd and RHS is even.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Seems fine. A bit overkill; you could pick a sequence of distinct elements in $[0,1]$ with the first two terms being $0$ and $1$, then $f(a_n)=a_{n+2}$ will do. This trick will work verbatim if you only add a finite number of elements to an infinite set.

Comment: @Ian Why not an official answer to clear the question form the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works, but it is a bit overly complicated. A simpler way to do it is to choose some sequence $a_n$ of distinct elements of $[0,1]$, with (say) $a_0=0,a_1=1$, and then define $f(a_n)=a_{n+2}$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise. This works whenever you add any finite number of elements to an infinite set.